# using Mongo ObjectId type for Meteor User ID's

Tags: mongodb, meteor, objectid

I'm using Meteor and have a question about overriding the default behavior of what type Meteor uses for User ID's.

I would like users to be uniquely identified by a `_id` field of type ObjectId instead of whatever type Meteor defaults to (string?). Is there something like a configuration parameter somewhere I can set in order to have this be the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You cannot use Objectd for the `_id` property of the `users` collection.

**Long answer:**

This has been posted as a [bug report at github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1834) but unfortunately rejected.

The rationale for the rejection is, while open to debate, that core packages need some design decisions towards simplicity and robustness. They do have a point, so do the developers who +1 this bug report (I'm one of them).

There has also been a [pull request](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/2285) to resolve another issue, while addressing this one, but that also got rejected due to some incompatibilities.

If you are really in need of a solution that requires ObjectId's all over, your safest bet is to create your own accounts package, which you can do by forking the original one towards your needs.

In fact [my comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1834#issuecomment-35499098) at that issue suggests a quick and dirty fix on the source code where the user's id is checked during the login flow which expects a string. You can for the package and change that check to accept ObjectId.

Comment: Today I quoted https://stackoverflow.com/a/24972966/435004 no less than four times in comments, commit messages and assertion failure messages. Thank you for your detailed analysis and advocacy towards the MDG.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm glad this information worked for you. Meteor is now acquired - https://forums.meteor.com/t/some-exciting-meteor-news/50313 - and has new leadership. Perhaps it is almost time to revive the request and even send in a PR.