# Meteor does not use a real objectId

Tags: mongodb, meteor, driver

Device drivers for Mongodb  work with the Mongo style

"_id" : ObjectId("572f6cb1d8a2860001521765") will fail with

the Meteor "_id" : "DPnd6ogRGhpwTRm7m"

Is there a work around ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Mongo ObjectId type for Meteor User ID's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964005/using-mongo-objectid-type-for-meteor-user-ids)

Comment: This issue comes up here quite often.

Comment: the free pascal driver can read but not update or delete meteor-mongo collections

Comment: I think there's a lot missing from your question. Device drivers on what OS?

Comment: https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/mongo4delphi reading is ok not update not delete with meteor collections

Comment: I suggest filing an issue on github with the package author but it doesn't look like a very active project.

Comment: yes a trial  with the mongo c-driver maybe best now